# Getting template error with symfony2 and sonata Admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have installed Sonata Admin bundle and Sonata Userbundle
When i go to

`/admin/dashboard` and click on list users i get this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Route "homepage" does not exist.") in
>   SonataUserBundle:Admin:Field/impersonating.html.twig at line 15.

What do i need to do

All other bundles Sonata page , news are working ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using this bundle but perhaps you have to implement your own homepage controller action with the name "homepage". Sonata probably used this route to go to your main page that you need to implement yourself !

Answer (score 3):

if you have:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
...
sonata_user_impersonating:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: SonataPageBundle:Page:catchAll }
```

just add

```
# app/config/config.yml
...
sonata_user:
    impersonating_route:    sonata_user_impersonating
```